# Is it possible to pass props upon redirect?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I have a redirect in my middleare where I redirect the user when not authenticated

```
export default function ({ store, redirect, route }) {
    console.log(route.name);
    if(!store.getters.isSignedIn && (route.name != 'authentication-sign-in' && route.name != 'authentication-sign-up'))
        return redirect('/authentication/sign-in');
}
```

I looked at

https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-middleware/

But my question is, can I pass a prop to route? So that I know that the user went to the sign in page by a redirect and show a snackbar telling the user he or she is not authenticated?

Comment: you can either add a query parameter with the redirect, or change the store in the middleware to have that information

Comment: @stranded the query parameter fixed it! Could you post it as an answer then i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect with a query parameter like `/authentication/sign-in?login=false` and then display the snackbar based on that query parameter.

`return redirect('/authentication/sign-in', { login: 'false' });`